# How to join two SQL queries?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Making two SQL queries into the same table

```
SELECT FirstName,
       LastName,
       LEFT(FirstName, 1) + '.' + LEFT(LastName, 1) AS Initial
FROM   ContactUpdates
```

This outputs:

```
FirstName    LastName    Initial
```

I want this to join this other one on the right side where Initial ends

```
SELECT LOWER(LEFT(FirstName, 1) + REPLACE(LastName,'''','' ) )
         + '@email.com' AS Email
FROM   ContactUpdates
```

In the end I want it to be

```
 FirstName    LastName    Initial    Email
```

But I can't figure out how to make them join any help?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT FirstName, 
    LastName, 
    LEFT(FirstName,1) + '.' + LEFT(LastName,1) AS Initial, 
    LOWER(LEFT(FirstName, 1) + REPLACE(LastName, '''', '')) + '@email.com' AS Email
FROM ContactUpdates
```

Answer (score 2):

Then simply append that column to the query:

```
SELECT FirstName
     , LastName
     , LEFT(FirstName,1) + '.' + LEFT(LastName,1) AS Initial 
     , LOWER(LEFT(FirstName,1) + REPLACE(LastName,'''','' ) ) + '@email.com' AS Email
FROM ContactUpdates
```